# How / Should I create my own Guice Scope

Tags: java, guice

We have a legacy application which we now load several instances of in a single JVM. We are now using Guice for dependency injection in our newer code, but the time has come to tackle the legacy application code.

The legacy application works in a number of threads which are created rather randomly (although all via a helper so we can add code there) and I think we need a scope to cover each instance of that application.

So, should I create my own scope? How should I make it cover multiple threads? Can I use the unique string that each instance of the application has in order to find the correct scope at the start of each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for a scope boils down to a single question: *Do you want to be able to inject the exact same object instance per environment-you-define, but have them differ between environments-you-define?* (This would mean, for object Foo, then each legacy-application-instance would receive a different Foo but within that legacy-application-instance's environment you would always receive the same Foo instance if it were requested.) If so, then scopes are what you want.

There are two important considerations when it comes to your scope's design and implementation:

1. All scopes are implemented as possibly-caching Provider wrappers.
2. Guice has no internal concept of threads, aside from synchronizing Singleton creation.

Singleton scopes are just a Provider-wrapper that creates the object once and saves it to return forever. Request and session scopes just determine the current request or session, wrapping the Provider to return the same instance or delegating to the inner Provider to create a new one if necessary. For unscoped objects, or for a hypothetical DoNothingScope, there is no wrapping needed—you get a new object every single time, like a normal Provider. Finally, importantly, for the thread-based scope example on Guice's [Custom Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes) page, the Scope merely returns an anonymous inner Provider that checks a `ThreadLocal<Map<Key, Object>>` to return an existing object if needed.

---

You can probably use that [Custom Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes) example as a starting point, with the following changes:

- Keep a `Map<LegacyAppInstance, Map<Key, Object>>`, because you're keying off the Application Instance rather than the Thread. Your unique String will work equally well as a key, but I don't know enough of the details about how accessible that is.
- You'll also want to keep a `ThreadLocal<LegacyAppInstance>` (or `ThreadLocal<String>`), which will let you determine the mapping from Thread to your legacy app instance at any time.
- `enter()` and `exit()` will require a few changes: you'll want to make a `enter(LegacyAppInstance)`, which you call from new threads to establish a link from the Thread to the LegacyAppInstance. You'll only call `exit` to destroy the `Map<Key, Object>` for that particular `LegacyAppInstance`, so all those created objects can be garbage-collected.
- Other than that, it's just the same: Return a Provider—which may be an anonymous inner Provider—that determines which thread you're on, determines which LegacyAppInstance is in play, and then returns an existing instance or creates a new one as needed.

Don't forget to bind the Scope instance itself as a singleton (`toInstance` bindings are necessarily Singletons) so you can get to it from your thread creation helper.